# logstash output couchbase for logstash v 2.x

Tags: logstash, couchbase

Is there currently a way to output to couchbase using logstash v2.x ?

The only resource Im finding online is that of an output-plugin that only supports versions [1.4, 2.0).This plugin doesn't seem to have any implementation or documentation.

If not, what is the simplest solution to output to couchbase from logstash currently? (I want to insert millions of documents into a couchbase bucket)

Is cbdocloader the only tool we can use to bulk load documents into the server?